# NumberFormat Java parse error

Tags: java

I have trouble when parsing with class `NumberFormat`, my data:

```
Cocacola 10 50
Tea 10 50
Water 10 50
Milk 10 50
Soda 10 50
```

I checked `readLine()` and it read correctly, but when I parse to double or integer value and print, it was wrong, this is stdout:

```
Cocacola 1.0 5 
Tea 1.0 5 
Water 1.0 5 
Milk 2.0 5 
Soda 1.0 5
```

And code:

```
String tmp[] = line.split("\\s+");
String name = tmp[0];
double cost=0;
int number=0;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
try {
    cost = nf.parse(tmp[1].trim()).doubleValue();
    number=nf.parse(tmp[2].trim()).intValue();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(name+" "+cost+" "+number+" ");
```

I cant use normal parse (`Double.parse()`, `Integer.parse()`, etc) because them make `NumberFormatException` error.

Comment: I hope it be 10.0 or 50 as file data

Comment: Have you tried to watch in debugger (or printing) values which you get after split?

Comment: I have printed before and after splited, values were corrected.
It just wrong after parse to number.

Comment: Please, execute the following line and tell me the output so I try to set your same locale: `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());`

Comment: Output is "en_US"

Comment: I tried with `NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);` and I got correct results.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try with this file in input?

```
Cocacola 10 50
GreenTea 10 50
Water 10 50
MilkTea 10 50
Soda 10 50
```

May be it is only the blank space (and split) that generate the errror, i.e.: "Green Tea", "Milk Tea",...
The split function in this line "Green Tea 10 50" generate `tmp["Green","Tea","10","50"]` and in this line of code:

```
cost = nf.parse(tmp[1].trim()).doubleValue();
```

You are trying to parse to number the String "Tea".

Comment: It have same as my file, after parase
10 -> 1.0 50 ->5
Correcty if print as String value.

Comment: I know that it is a trivial question but, are you sure the program is reading the file you think it reads?

Comment: Sorry, I got copy wrong file. Sdtout posted was of this file
Cocacola 10 50
Tea 15 50
Water 10 50
Milk 20 50
Soda 15 50

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to the fact that you could have spaces in the middle of your name so using `line.split("\\s+")` cannot work as you could get an array of `String` with a `length` greater than `3` while your code expects a length of exactly `3`.

You should use a **regular expression** that will define the expected format of your line, something like this:

```
// Meaning a sequence of any characters followed by a space
// then a double followed by a space and finally an integer 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*) (\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?) (\\d+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String name = matcher.group(1);
    double cost = Double.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
    int number = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.printf("%s %f %d%n", name, cost, number);
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
        String.format("line '%s' doesn't have the expected format", line)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use 2 different formats, one for the price another for the quantity. You could you try this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    cost = nf.parse(tmp[1].trim())).doubleValue();
    number = nf.parse(tmp[2].trim()).intValue();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you try exactly this code:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
double d = numberFormat.parse("10").doubleValue();
int q = numberFormat.parse("50").intValue();
System.out.println("Cost: " + d);
System.out.println("Quantity: " + q);
```

The output would be:

10.0 
50

Is not your expected code?

Comment: I have excuted but output still wrong after parsed.

Comment: @ĐàmĐìnhĐinh check your input values, because the example i did was with hardcoded values and worked, so probably some of your input value is wrong